# How to use a custom .csv dataset in TensorFlow Recommenders library?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, recommendation-engine

I'm new to tensorflow. I want to train a recommendation model on my dataset using the TensorFlow Recommenders library and the simple code provided at:

https://github.com/tensorflow/recommenders

I want to know how can I use (load and feed to the model) my custom .csv file in the following format instead of loading the built-in Movielens dataset?

| user_id | item_id | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 8 | 3 |
| 5 | 12 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

My Tensorflow versions:

tensorflow==2.4.0

tensorflow-datasets==4.2.0

tensorflow-recommenders==0.4.0

Answer (score 5):

```
import pandas as pd

DATA_URL = "D:/ratings.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(DATA_URL)
ratings = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(df)).map(lambda x: {
    "user_id": str(x["user_id"]),
    "item_id": str(x["item_id"]),
    "rating": float(x["rating"])
})
```

Comment: how about timestamp?